# How to avoid exceptions in utilizing a value of datagridrow when row is not selected

Tags: c#, wpf, exception, select, datagrid

I have a Datagrid and I get the value of selected Datagridrow through below code. If I run my code after selecting a certain Datagridrow, it's finely working. However, on clients side(users of my software), there's always lots of exceptional cases like clicking button without selecting Datagridrow.
Setting the selectedindex=0 or 1 of Datagrid didn't solve this problem.

How I can avoid these ArgumentOutOfRangeException, Nullreferenceexception?
Your excellence will be highly appreciated. Thank you so much !

```
private void buttonFrequentsentencesdeletion_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Button bu = sender as Button;

        if (sender != null)
        {
            object item = dataGrid_Frequentsentences.SelectedItem;
            string FSdatagridID = (dataGrid_Frequentsentences.SelectedCells[2].Column.GetCellContent(item) as TextBlock).Text;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before using the selected item validate if it's null

```
private void buttonFrequentsentencesdeletion_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{ 
     if (dataGrid_Frequentsentences.SelectedItem != null)
```

Comment: Oh, it's working fine. Please understand that my major is biochemistry not related to software industry..After struggling so long time alone, it seems I've became too dependent to stackoverflow. My deepest appreciation to you making me 1 step ahead..Thank you so much !